# Jquery animate from right bottom corner to

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a UI using jquery and css. I was trying to build one page for the navigation using jQuery animate. What I have now were four tiles in the page. I was able to increase the height and width of the top two tiles so that it occupies the whole of the parent div. But I was not able to do the same for the bottom two DIVs.

I tried a lot of things but the problem is that I can use float left and float right for the top two DIVs but I cannot do the same for the bottom two DIVs. I don't know what to use for the bottom 
two DIVs.

All I want is a kind of animation as shown in the figure so that Child3 and Child4 expand from their position to occupy full height and width of the parent DIV by expanding from their place.

[image: Animation of Bottom Right Div]

[image: Animation of Bottom Left Div]

What I'm doing now is I'm using

```
$("child1").animate({"height":someheight,"width":somewidth},500);
```

I'm increasing and decreasing the height and width based on the present height of the div so that it has the zoom in and zoom out effect.

I have attached the JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uxuzfq5x/ for the top two DIVs and I wanted to implement the above for bottom two DIVs.

I'm a novice in jQuery and please  do correct me if I have made any mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this using jQuery **[`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** method

```js
function f1() {
  $(".child3").css("z-index", 1000).animate({
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%"
  }, 1000).animate({
    width: "49.8%",
    height: "49%"
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).css("z-index", 100);
    f2();
  });
}

function f2() {
  $(".child4").css("z-index", 1000).animate({
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%"
  }, 1000).animate({
    width: "49.8%",
    height: "49%"
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).css("z-index", 100);
    f1();
  });
}
f1();
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 49.8%;
  height: 49%;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.child1 {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.child2 {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.child3 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.child {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">Child1</div>
  <div class="child child2">Child2</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="child child3">Child3</div>
  <div class="child child4">Child4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxuzfq5x/4/)

```
   $(function(){

     $(".child").animate({"height":"100px","width":"200px"},500);

    });
```